# Finding $p\cdot K\left(s\right)E\left(s\right)+q\cdot K\left(s\right)^{2}$ such that it is a known constant

Tags: calculus, summation, elliptic-integrals

Recently I got interested in the Series of Form,
$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{r^p}{A^{r}}\binom{2r}{r}^{b}$$

I was able to derive this,
$$\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\right)\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{a+br}{x^{r}}\binom{2r}{r}^3=\left(\frac{b}{1-2\alpha}\right)K\left(\alpha\right)E\left(\alpha\right)+\left(a-\frac{16b}{32-x\alpha}\right)K\left(\alpha\right)^{2}$$
Where,
$K(k)$ is the Complete Elliptical Integral of the First Kind and $E(k)$ is the Complete Elliptical Integral of the Second Kind with the following convention:
$$K\left(k\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\left(1-kt^{2}\right)}}dt$$
$$E\left(k\right)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1-k\sin^{2}t}dt$$
and,
$$\alpha=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{64}{x}}$$

Now to make the series have an Elegant Form we need to eliminate the Elliptical Integrals from the Right Side.

What I mean by elegant form is something like,
$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{a+br}{x^{r}}\binom{2r}{r}^3=\frac{C}{\pi^2}$$
Where $a, b$ are Integers and $C$ should be a known constant, preferably an Integer but other closed form expressions work too!
$x$ would most likely be a power of $2$ but I am not sure on that.


Modifying the Equations a bit we can write it as,
$$\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\right)\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left[q+p\left(1-s\right)\right]+\left[p\left(1-2s\right)\right])r}{\left[\frac{16}{s\left(1-s\right)}\right]^{r}}\right)\binom{2r}{r}^3=p\cdot K\left(s\right)E\left(s\right)+q\cdot K\left(s\right)^{2}$$

Now the main problem is that I haven't been able to find $p, q, s$ such that
$$p\cdot K\left(s\right)E\left(s\right)+q\cdot K\left(s\right)^{2}$$
is a known constant.

EDIT:
I searched out some values for the Elliptical Integrals and was able to at least derive this:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1+6r}{2^{8r}}\right)\binom{2r}{r}^3=\frac{4}{\pi}$$

Comment: The last series in your question which sums up to $4/\pi$ is the famous (and one of the simplest) series given by Ramanujan in his paper *Modular equations and approximations to $\pi$*. The relation which you seek between elliptic integrals is also available from Ramanujan's results in the same paper. See [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4733525/72031) for more details.

Comment: The approach in your question is essentially the same as the one provided by Ramanujan in his paper (referenced in previous comment). The idea is to use hypergeometric series for $(2K/\pi)^2$ and differentiate it. I have explained Ramanujan's technique in my blog posts :https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-1.html?m=0 and https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-2.html?m=0 and I also provide the proof for the last series of your question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank You for the Comments Sir! I was actually planning to study these topics from your blogposts (just discovered them a few days ago).

Comment: See another series summed up using Ramanujan's technique at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4635491/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes! I actually got interested in these series when I heard about Gourevitch's Conjecture which has not been proven till yet as far as I know.

Comment: Did you want to mean in the right hand: $\frac{C}{\pi}$ when you say: "...elegant form is something like...". Best all.

Comment: @User Well I took $\pi^2$ to the Right Hand Side, It just happens to be that the Constant $C$ itself had a $\pi$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linked answer ([Integrals of elliptic integrals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716012/integrals-of-elliptic-integrals)) we proved:

$$K(s)E(s)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}\frac{2-s^2}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)(2n)!^3}{2^{8n}n!^6}{\left(\frac{s^4}{
s^2-1}\right)}^n.\tag{1}$$
Which is a consequence of Clausen's formula:
$$K^{2}(s)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!^3}{2^{8n}n!^6}\left(\frac{s^4}{s^2-1} \right)^{n}.\tag{2}$$

To find $p,q,s$ such $pK(s)E(s)+qK^2(s)$ is a known constant, you will need the elliptic singular moduli.
If you consider $s=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ then :

$$K^2(s)=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi^2}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n)!^3}{2^{9n}n!^6}=\frac{\Gamma{(1/4)}^4}{16\pi},\tag{3}$$
and
$$E(s)K(s)=\frac{3\pi^2}{8\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n)!^3(2n+1)}{2^{9n}n!^6}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^4}{32\pi}.\tag{4}$$
So if $p=1$, $q=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $s=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ then:
$$pK(s)E(s)+qK^2(s)=\frac{\pi}{4}.\tag{5}$$
If you consider Landen's transformation $K(s)(1+s)=K(\frac{2\sqrt{s}}{1+s})$ applied to $(1)$ and $(2)$ and $s=\sqrt{2}-1$
you will get Bauer's series and you will find another relation of the type of $(5)$.

Comment: Thank You for the Answer!

Comment: Also Paramanand's blog is very extensive and also explains the theory of modular equations. Take a look!